# Portable text based console manipulator

Tags: c++, c, console, terminal

Applications can manipulate text based consoles or terminals, and change their colors, set cursor position. The supported approaches are:

- *For Unix-like systems:* There is [`ANSI escape code`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).
- *For Windows systems:* There is APIs like [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- ...

but, **is there any lightweight and portable C/C++ library which handles differences between operating systems just for colors and cursor?** and do nothing if it was technically impossible but best effort.

*Note: I'm not searching for heavy external tools to emulate unix-like terminals (like Cygwin, Msys-rxvt, ...). I think a simple portability will be achieved with Windows APIs and ANSI escape codes.* *And not ncurses because it's heavy and has many functionality to full control console and I think it needs emulation.*

Comment: @Nim: It needs terminal emulator for Windows - Read my updated question

Comment: @MasoudM.: There is PDCurses on windows (**[MonoCurses](http://www.mono-project.com/Libraries#Curses)** apparently uses it)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Alright, i finally found a portable and easy to use library: [`rlutil.h`](https://github.com/tapio/rlutil)

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rlutil.h"
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        rlutil::setColor(i);
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*but, i will be glad for other suggestions.*

Comment: Good find. although I wonder if I should doubt the developer's proficiency for his color choices on his website! :)

Comment: Does anyone know how to reset the colors to default? Once I change them the terminal's default color becomes whatever color I used last, and no color actually maps to the default color on any of the terminals I tried (`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, and the venerable `cmd.exe`)

Comment: Tough to present the license agreement for it to my legal people. :-)