# Display image in console application

Tags: c++, image

I am writing a program, and I thought that it would be better with images (I am creating console application). So I want to know if it's possible? And if it is how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of a console do you have?

Comment: It's probably possible, but you forgot to tell us things like what  operating system you use, and if you want to show ready made pictures or draw the images yourself.

Comment: Well I use CodeBlocks GCC compiler, and my operating system is win7 and I want show ready made pictures.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art), There are many open source libraries which convert image to ASCIIs, such as [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca).

[image]

And if you want use colored images, you can use [rlutil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881314/952747).

Comment: Yes, Read [Portable text based console manipulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876241/portable-text-based-console-manipulator)

Comment: +1 just for thinking outside the box. Or maybe in this case it was inside the box?

Answer (score 1):

Consoles are designed to display characters only. With some [very crude exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15507226/5987) it is not possible to display images unless you open another window.