# Code:Blocks is my IDE How to make my C++ executable

Tags: c++, colors, exe

Ok I have seen questions similar, but none seem to be what I'm looking for. I have just designed a simple math program. Nothing special, just doing it to learn..

Back on topic, How do i make it so that it is executable from desktop? So that it is just like Code:Blocks and I can double-click the icon on my desktop and it will open by itself not in Code:Blocks.

Another question, a little off topic but how do you add colors and stuff on a program, while mine just opens into the boring black cmd prompt.?

First question is the most important, but if someone would like to answer the last one that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you can run your program from the IDE, then you have its executable binary file somewhere near your project. Just find that `.exe` file and copy it (or shortcut) to your Desktop.

To coloring your console program, read this [Portable text based console manipulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876241/portable-text-based-console-manipulator/7881314#7881314).

Comment: for the first part I haven't tried the second but it wouldn't open on double-click but I could run it from terminal. But what that did was the same as in the ide it was just a command prompt. Do I have to code something different so that it will open by itself. I want it to be just like opening google Chrome (for this example we will say its wrote in C++) that opens by itself and is a program how do I make my program like that.

Comment: Chrome and applications like that are window-based applications and yours is a console application. To have a program like them, you should write your code based on forms. I offer you go and read about Qt.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but what is Qt?

Comment: [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) is a C++ framework which has many tools to make a visual and window based applications. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29)

Comment: Thank you. Is that the same thing I would use to make like an AV program./