# How to change look and feel of console?

Tags: windows, console, console-application

I would like to know if there is some library which is responsible for changing the look and feel of console. I found some interesting program which displays coloured text and has gray bar overhead. How it's possible?

[image: Some console]

Comment: How is this related to C++?

Comment: One way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Jori: because I use this language.

Comment: This probably should be in superuser,  if you are looking for a utility/application

Comment: @chris: What about the bar shown on the attachment?

Comment: @deepspace, The background color can be changed as well.

Comment: but this won't be visible all the time.. this one is.

Comment: It is part of the application, I expect. With `ncurses` you can do this sort of thing, or if you write just a little bit of code to handle your output, you can "scroll all but the top line" using ANSI escape sequences (but it gets quite messy, quite quickly).

Comment: @Jori Because the program is programmed in C++.

Comment: @cybermonkey: That changes nothing.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876241/portable-text-based-console-manipulator)  asking about console libraries from the portability perspective. Someone mentions [rlutil](http://tapiov.net/rlutil/) which would seem like a good start. Also [a quick google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%2b%2b%20windows%20console%20library) brings up a few results. [ConsoleLibrary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console-library/) looks ok.

Comment: Link-only answers are not acceptable

Comment: @Puppy I wouldn't say this answer is of link-only. Low quality, yes, link-only, no.