# How can I clear my screen before each loop iteration?

Tags: c++, c

How can I clear my screen for each time through the loop? I mean I don't want to print the menu again. When I choose an option, this will show me that you want to repeat or go back to main menu or exit. Is it possible using `if`/`else` or will I have to use `switch` for that?

```
do
{
    cout << "\t **Manue**" << endl;
    cout << "1)   Print a Table " << endl;
    cout << "2)   Find the Prime Number " << endl;
    cout << "3)   Find the Factorial" << endl;
    cout << "4)   Exit Program " << endl;
    cout << "\nPlease select an option : ";
    cin >> option;
    if (option == 1)
    {
        int a, b;
        cout << "Enter the number that you want to have its table" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        for (int c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
        {
            b = c*a;
            cout << "The table is " << b << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (option == 2)
    {
        int num, flag = 0, i = 2;
        cout << "Enter the number that you want to check is a Prime or Not :" << endl;
        cin >> num;
        while (i < num)
        {
            if (num%i == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if (flag == 0)
            cout << "**Number is prime**\n" << endl;
        else
            cout << "\n**Number is not prime**\n" << endl;
    }
    else if (option == 3)
    {
        int i, fact = 1;
        cout << "Enter the number to find its Factorial" << endl;
        cin >> i;
        for (int n = i; n > 1; n--)
        {
            fact = fact *n;
            cout << fact << endl;

        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Invalid Option entered" << endl;
    }
    }
    while (option != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `system("cls")` on Windows or `system("clear")` on Unix as a quick hack. Not recommended though. For serious stuff you should use a library like ncurses.

Comment: your do while should be terminated as (option) , and in the menu make it 0) to exit

Comment: You can try outputting a form-feed escape sequence `\f` which will often clear the screen.

Comment: I am done with clearing the menu but how i will get it back each time i want .? to go to other options?

Comment: @Davidwatson The same way you got it there the first time? Output it again.

Comment: @zenith   There is a problem that first time when i choose a choice 1. it clears the screen .which is ok. 

but when it shows some results it again shows the menu automatically .that i dont want .

i want that after the execution the program ask from the user that you want to go to Menu. press this    you want to repeat press this . exit press this...

Comment: `ncurses` may be overkill. It takes over the entire screen. The OP just wants to clear the screen. (Personally, I think that's almost always a bad idea; if *your* program clears *my* screen, you might be erasing information that I didn't want erased.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: One of the nice things with ncurses is, when the program exits, *your screen is restored to its previous content* (as *opposed* to all the other solutions posted here).

Comment: Look into [rlutil.h](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7881314/952747) portable in Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You will not find a portable way to do it without using a library hiding the possible specificities of terminals. That's the reason why libraries like `curses` and all its derivatives like `ncurses` were written.

And olders can still remember the time where we used print terminals, yes like a typing machine with a serial interface : everything typed on keyboard went to computer, everything written went to ... paper ! No hope to clear a menu on that ...

Ok those days are now gone, but do not expect having a simple way to clear screen in a cmd.exe under Windows, on the console on a Unix like system, and on any terminal emulation program.

So you have only three choices :

- be strictly portable and just output several new lines - no clearing, only vertical spacing
- be less portable and try `\f` that works on different systems (but not guaranteed everywhere)
- use a `ncurses` derivative library.

Comment: Printing "several" new lines might not work. I currently have a window that's 130 lines tall. `'\f'` typically *doesn't* work (in particular, `xterm` doesn't clear the screen when it sees a formfeed character). `ncurses` could be overkill; it takes over the screen, when the OP apparently just wants to clear it.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple idea is that you can use the [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) command and issue a `clear` (or `cls`) in order to clear the screen in the output and present/refresh the new state of your menu. If you want to create something simple it is not a bad idea because you don't have to read anything about ncurses, etc. Also, define a constant of the form

```
#define CLEARSCREEN system ( "cls" )
```

so that you switch between cls/clear very quickly. Note that on Windows I think this also requires the library `process.h`; i.e. you will also need a statement of the form

```
#include <process.h>
```

somewhere on top.

Comment: I'd write that as a function, not as a macro.

Comment: No problem at all. I only wrote down one idea.

Answer (score 1):

**Ncurses.**

Expanding on Serge's answer, `<iostream>` and `std::cout` are mostly for line-based output, with no concept of "the screen". If you want to provide a menu-driven user interface, with options offered, user input taken, and output generated in response to user input in a loop, you should really take a look at [**ncurses**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which offers just that kind of functionality.

Ncurses is supported on many platforms, and offers bindings for many different languages. For a bare-bones example, though, I opted for "raw" C, which is easy enough to adopt in C++ code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINELEN 50

int main()
{
    int c;
    char input[LINELEN];

    initscr();

    do {
        erase();
        mvprintw( 1, 1, "**Manue**\n" );
        mvprintw( 2, 1, "1) Print a Table\n" );
        mvprintw( 3, 1, "2) Find the Prime Number\n" );
        mvprintw( 4, 1, "3) Find the Factorial\n" );
        mvprintw( 5, 1, "4) Exit Program\n" );
        mvprintw( 7, 1, "Please select an option.\n" );
        refresh();

        getnstr( input, LINELEN );

        erase();
        mvprintw( 1, 1, "You entered: '%s'. (Press a key.)\n", input );
        refresh();

        int c = getch();
    } while ( strcmp( input, "4" ) );

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

It should be easy to expand from there. Regarding a comment by Keith Thompson, this has the additional benefit of **not** actually erasing the user's terminal -- once `endwin()` is called, the previous contents are restored.

Answer (score 0):

Add the header file

```
#include < stdlib.h >
```

and use the function

```
system("cls");
```

wherever you want to clear your screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you don't want exactly clearing of screen - as you wrote :

> There is a problem that first time when i choose a choice 1. it clears the screen .which is ok. but when it shows some results it again shows the menu automatically .that i dont want . i want that after the execution the program ask from the user that you want to go to Menu. press this you want to repeat press this . exit press this...

I think you might be talking about submenus : when user chooses option in menu you want to give user a choice : whether do the same action again or return to menu. This is a simple example of menu-submenu:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_main() {
    std::cout << "Main menu: [a, b, q (quit)]" << std::endl;
}

void print_submain() {
    std::cout << "Go back to main? [y/n]" << std::endl;
}

void submain() {
    char suboption;
    do {
        std::cout << "Do domething" << std::endl;
        print_submain();
        std::cin >> suboption;
    } while ( suboption != 'y');
}

int main() {
    char option;
    do {
        print_main();
        std::cin >> option;
        // it doesn't matter if switch or if-else is used
        switch(option) {
        case 'a':
            submain();
            break;
        case 'b':
            submain();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    } while (option != 'q');
    return 0;
}
```

You can have different `submain` functions, doing different things and with example above user can perform them as long as they want to and then return to main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Do a  `system("pause");` before `system("cls");`. The user will have to press ENTER or any key to return to the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in your each iteration:-

```
void clrscr()
{
    system("@cls||clear");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";
```

Comment: Please take some time in making your explanation more thorough. Although the code you posted might work perfectly, it will be more helpful for other community members to take benefit from your answer if you describe your solution first