# How to make color changes in every line array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi

I have a question to ask for everyone in this site. i want to make my array statement color changes, in each line. I mean, each line of my array statement has different color. here is my program

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color 0B");
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
    cout<<"\n Printing array index in char program";
    char data[27]={' ','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<28;x++)
    {
        cout<<"\n\n Input array index : ";
        cin>>x;
        cout<<"Character you are looking for is "<<data[x];
    }
    getch();
}
```

i want the changing color in `cout<<"\n\n Input array index : ";` statement and `cout<<"Character you are looking for is "<<data[x];` statement. Help me please :)

Comment: Just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876241/portable-text-based-console-manipulator). There's also [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `conio` then you can use `textcolor (int)` for coloring.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
    cout<<"\n Printing array index in char program";
    char data[27]={' ','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<27;x++)
    {
        textcolor(x+1);
        cout<<"\n\n Input array index : ";
        cin>>x;
        cout<<"Character you are looking for is "<<data[x];
    }
    getch();
}
```

If you are not using `conio` then try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HANDLE  hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
    cout<<"\n Printing array index in char program";
    char data[27]={' ','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<27;x++)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, x+1);
        cout<<"\n\n Input array index : ";
        cin>>x;
        cout<<"Character you are looking for is "<<data[x];
    }
}
```

Small advice don't use `conio` , `conio.h` is indeed not a standard C header.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Windows [console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN);
std::cout << "This text should be green" << std::endl;
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't really know (and can't test) if it works with the C++ standard output stream, or if you have to use [`WriteConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).</sub>